# Can`t find Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for Apple Push Notification service

Tags: ios, xcode

I`m trying to add to my app Push Notification service. I have already successfully distributed my app via Enterprise Distribution, by following all instructions. But now enabling Apple Push Notification service i need Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file and accidentally deleted him. How can i get another CSR file without creating new certificate and going through the hard process of app distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it tells you in the provisioning portal - open keychain access --> app menu--> certificate assistant -->  request a certificate from a certificate authority.

However, you may have to re-sign your app with the new certificate that is eventually generated. The CSR is the "easy" bit!